# Proof for Equation with binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have problems prooving following equation. I tried to use induction, but I did not suceed.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac {n}{2} \rfloor}\binom{n}{k} \frac{n-2k+1}{n-k+1}= \binom{n}{\lfloor \frac {n}{2} \rfloor}$$

The context of the equation is combinatorical:

Let $\lambda$ be a partition of n, then $f^\lambda$ ist the amount of Young Tableauxs of shape $\lambda$. (See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Tableaux)

I found out using the hook-formula:
$f^{(n-k,k)}=\binom{n}{k} \frac{n-2k+1}{n-k+1}$.
So the upper equation I am looking for is the sum over these amounts of Young-Tableauxs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n \choose k} \frac{n-2k+1}{n-k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n \choose k} \bigg(1-\frac{k}{n-k+1}\bigg)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n \choose k} -\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}$$
But we know that $\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}={n \choose {k-1}}$. So-
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n \choose k} \frac{n-2k+1}{n-k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n \choose k} -{n \choose {k-1}}={n \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}}$$
due to telescoping.

Comment: In the telescoping step I get a different result. Can you tell me where my fault is?
$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n \choose k} -{n \choose {k-1}}={n \choose 0}-{n \choose -1}+{n \choose 1}-{n \choose 0}+...+{n \choose {\lfloor} \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}-{n \choose {\lfloor} \frac{n}{2} \rfloor-1}=-{n \choose -1}+{n \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}}$

Comment: At $k=0$, the actual expression has value $n \choose 0$. So, when you have $n \choose {-1}$ in the expression, you must take it as zero. Then, you get the same value.